# Find the domain of $x^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus

Find the domain of $f(x)=x^{2/3}$.  Now, $0^2=0$ and $\sqrt[3]{0}=0$, all positive and negative numbers squared will give positive answer, these numbers can give us cuberoot, so entire real line is the domain, am I correct? (one of the online help provided the answer as $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0\}$ (all non-negative real numbers), why negative numbers are not included in the domain, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What online tool gave $[0,\infty)$ as the answer, and what was the input? (On the other hand, the domain of $x^{3/2}$ *is* the nonnegative real numbers...)

Comment: Are you talking about the range of $f(x)$?

Comment: can I disclose the website name here?

Comment: @Vikram: Why not?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+the+function+x%5E%282%2F3%29

Comment: Fractional powers aren't as simple as we think. Arturo below says that $x^{2/3}$ means $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$, and this is one interpretation. Reasonable people might want $x^{2/3}$ to mean the exact same thing that $x^{4/6}$ does. Again, we could interpret this as $\sqrt[6]{x^4}$, and all real numbers are valid input. But why shouldn't this also be a valid interpretation: $(\sqrt[6]{x})^4$? This version cannot have negative input. So there is an issue here that comes down to what the definition of raising to a fractional power really means.

Comment: The only situations where $a^b$ is totally unambiguous is when $a\geq0$ or $b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Powers of exponents are also unambiguous if $b$ is a completely reduced fraction. Since $x^3$ is defined for all integers than its inverse, $x^{1/3}$ must also have complete domain. Remember using your rule $x^{6/2}$ is also undefined unless $6/2$ is simplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, $x^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{x^2}$.

Since we can compute $x^2$ for any real number $x$, and since we can compute a cubic root for any real number, whether it be positive, negative, or zero, the domain is all real numbers.

On the other hand, as Kannappan hints, the *range* of this function is $[0,\infty)$. So you should really check the input of that on-line tool.

Comment: One online tool that claims the domain is $\[0,\infty)$ is [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^%282%2F3%29). It chooses a complex branch for negative arguments, possibly in an attempt to have only a single cut in the complex $x$-plane.

Comment: thanx Henning, you are correct about the online tool name

Comment: and I am not interested in complex numbers, so my question is answered by Arturo

Comment: And yet, the plot given by Wolfram Alpha clearly includes negative numbers. Yet another reason for me not to like Wolfram Alpha all that much...

Comment: @Arturo: To be fair, to does give the domian under the subheading "properties as a real function".

Comment: @Henning: Right: WA contradicts itself, giving the full domain in the *graph*, but giving a truncated domain under "properties as a real function." Hence, my lack of trust.

Comment: It's not clear to me that $x^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{x^2}$ by definition.

Comment: @lhf: That's the standard way of extending exponents to from integers to rational numbers: define $x^{1/n}$ as the inverse of $y\mapsto y^n$; then define $x^{a/b}$ as $(x^a)^{1/b}$. Of course, one can use different definitions. "The nice thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from."

Comment: Yeah, I've just checked baby Rudin and it's like that there. But there is the definition via $\exp$, which I guess amounts to the same thing. In both cases however one is limited to $x>0$.

Comment: @lhf: Most of the time, you can't define $\exp$ until you've developed "enough" exponentials (unless you want to go the route of Taylor series; or as the inverse of $\log$, with $\log$ defined via integrals), so the definition for rational exponents often precedes that of $\exp$ (making it difficult to define $x^{a/b}$ as $\exp(b\log(x)/a)$). One is limited to $x\gt 0$ for *arbitrary* rational exponents, but one can extend the rational exponents definition when $b$ is odd to negative exponents.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is unfortunately context-dependent. That's a fancy way of saying that on a test the answer is what your instructor says it is.  For whatever it is worth, Wolfram Alpha thinks that the domain is the non-negative reals.

I assume we are working in the reals.  We are concerned with the domain of $x^y$, where $y$ is a *positive* real number. (I am taking $y$ positive to avoid division by $0$ issues, and $0$-th power issues.)

There is general agreement that $x^y$ is defined when $x\ge 0$. But there are disagreements in the case $x<0$.

If $y$ is *irrational*, there is general agreement that $x^y$ is not defined at negative $x$.

If $y$ is *rational*, and $y$ can be expressed as $a/b$, where $a$ is an odd integer, and $b$ is an even integer, there is general agreement that $x^y$ is not defined at negative $x$.

When $y$ is a rational, which, when put in lowest terms, has an odd denominator, there is disagreement.

In high school, generally the convention is that in that case, $x^y$ is defined when $x$ is negative.  And that convention is not confined to high school.

But when we are dealing with exponential *functions*, with $y$ thought of as *variable*, there are good arguments for considering, for example, $(-2)^{2/3}$ to be undefined.

The issue is this. Consider the function $(-2)^y$.   Arbitrarily close to $2/3$, there are irrational $y$ at which $(-2)^y$ is definitely not defined. So even if we consider $(-2)^{2/3}$ to have a meaning, the function $(-2)^y$ is not continuous at $y=2/3$.

Another argument is that a common definition of $x^y$ is that $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$. Note that $\ln x$ is not defined when $x$ is negative. Of course, $\ln x$ is not defined at $x=0$, but that generally does not stop people from considering $x^{2/3}$ defined at $x=0$.

Comment: The problem with second argument is that if $y=1$ for $x^{y}$ then $x=e^{\ln(x)}$. At $x=-1$ this is not the case. It is possible when $x$ is positive but $y=x$ must still have a negative domain. For your first argument is there a theorem stating a function must be continuous at point to be definable?

Comment: Certainly there is no theorem, or convention, that a function must be continuous at $a$ to be defined at $a$. However, if certain "natural" manipulations are correct for positive $a$ but incorrect for negative $a$, it may be useful to restrict the domain. That said, we certainly would not want $(-1)^n$ to be taken away from us!