# What is the Domain of $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Find the Domain of $$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ I have Confusion on Negative Real numbers. if $x=-2$  then $f(x)$ is not Real, but if $x=-3$ ,$f(x)$ is Real. I am unable to figure out which set of negative real numbers come into the Domain.Books give the Domain as $\mathbb{R^+}$

Comment: Be sure to check... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109316/find-the-domain-of-x2-3

 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398224/what-is-the-domain-of-xx-when-x0

 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/can-the-graph-of-xx-have-a-real-valued-plot-below-zero

 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695701/how-can-we-describe-the-graph-of-xx-for-negative-values

Answer (score 9):

If you are thinking along the lines of $\sqrt[3]{-27}=-3$, that's not the same as $(-27)^{1/3}$.

$(-27\pm i\varepsilon)^{1/3}$ are both nowhere near a negative real (where $\varepsilon$ is a small positive real), so if $(-27)^{1/3}$ had meaning, a desire to be working with continuous functions would mean $(-27)^{1/3}$ is not a negative real.

These considerations should convince someone that it's not a good idea to say $\sqrt[3]{x}=x^{1/3}$ when $x$ is negative.

If you do insist that $\sqrt[3]{-27}=(-27)^{1/3}$, then why isn't it the same as $(-27)^{2/6}=\sqrt[6]{(-27)^2}$, which is a positive real? You run into trouble like this if you insist that $\sqrt[3]{x}=x^{1/3}$ when $x$ is negative.

Comment: I fully concur!

Comment: @alex.jordan I do not believe $e^{x\ln{1/x}}\neq{x}^{\frac{1}{x}}$ when $x<0$. Plus $x^{p/q}$ it is not equal to $\sqrt[q]{x^p}$. You must not do anything with $p/q$ when $x$ is negative.

Comment: Sorry I meant $e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}\neq{x}^{1/x}$.

Comment: @Arbuja Yes, that's my opinion: you *must* have $x^{1/3}=x^{2/6}$, so you need that $x>0$.

Comment: @Arbuja When you apply fractional exponents, you need to assume the base is positive (or apply some contorted conditions). So $x\mapsto x^3$ is defined also for $x<0$; this does not mean that $x^3=x^{6/2}$ for all $x$. Unfortunately exponential notation is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: @alex.jordan I apologize you did not directly answer the OP's post. The OP could misguided that there is no domain.

Comment: I don't see the appeal here, but perhaps  I do not practice enough complex analysis. By the same logic, I apparently have to believe  that $x\neq x^{1/1}$ because $x^{1/1}=x^{2/2}$ 'convinces me' that $x^{1/1}$ has no negative domain. I can understand wanting to keep the calculus of rational exponents crisp by restricting domains to be positive, though, which is apparently the intention here.

Comment: I rolled back this answer to how I wrote it. Please, if you don't understand the answer, don't try to edit it.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm not saying what you are saying about $x^{1/1}$ or $x^{2/2}$. Those are both just as you would expect them to be: $x^1$. What I am saying is  the latter is only reliably equal to $\sqrt{x^2}$ in the case where $x$ is positive. I'm saying that no matter how much Arbuja religiously believes that $\sqrt[q]{x^p}$ and $x^{p/q}$ meant the same thing, they in fact do not. They have distinct definitions, which coincide when $x$ is positive.

Comment: @Arbuja I have failed to convince you that you have been trained incorrectly to believe that $x^{p/q}$ is the same thing as $\sqrt[p]{x^q}$ [even for reduced rational $p/q$.] So I will appeal to a CAS. [Type "cube root of -8" into Wolfram Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cube+root+of+-8) Then [type "(-8)^(1/3)" into Wolfram Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-8%29%5E%281%2F3%29) While I normally would never use WA to "prove" anything, hopefully this opens you to the possibility that you are using a nonstandard meaning for exponentiation.

Comment: @alex.jordan Clicking on your links I got the cube root of $-8$ to be $-2$ but I got the result from $(-8)^{1/3}$ to be $2\sqrt[3]{-1}$ but the decimal form is a complex number. As I said before $e^{\ln{x}}\neq{x}$ for example taking $x=-1$ proves you should use identity for negative numbers.

Comment: @Arbuja Well, serves me right for trying to use WA to make a point. It's not the details of the output that matters; it's that the outputs are two different things. Anyway, you sincerely believe that $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$, and I don't. It's pointless to continue if you feel that $(-1)^{1/3}$ is $-1$, for example. We are using different definitions for $x^y$. I assert that mine is more standard, and is used by computers etc. Yours stems from extending the relation $x^{1/q}=\sqrt[q]{x}$  to apply to negative real $x$. The two meanings are incompatible for nonpositive $x$ and noninteger $y$.

Answer (score 1):

General observation: given a real valued function $f$, we can write
$$
f(x)=\exp(\log(f(x)))
$$
*only* when $f>0$.

Hence in your case $\Bbb R^{+}$ is clearly contained in the domain of the function $f(x)=x^{\frac1 x}$.
It remains to show that no other point is admitted in the domain.

$0$ is clearly out.

Then if $x<0$ what you have is a power of a real negative number. But in the system of real numbers, the power is defined *only* for positive base. Hence no negative number could be taken in account.

Thus the domain of your function is given by all and only positive real numbers, $\Bbb R^{+}$.

Comment: @Arthur Do you mean $-\sqrt[3]{1/3}$? Anyway, the question is very confusing, why is f(x) not being real a problem? Given the confusing state of the question, I don't dislike this answer.

Comment: the domain of a function f(x) is not the domain of e^log(f(x)), although in this case the result is the same

Comment: @Joe, we cant change the Definition of the function, because if we do so, the Domain changes. For example Domain of Definition of $$f(x)=\log_{10}\left(x^2+2x+1\right)$$ is $\mathbb{R}-{-1}$, But when we write $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=2\log_{10}(x+1)$$ The Domain has Changed to $(-1 \: \infty)$

Comment: He hasn't changed the definition, as the definition of $x^{1/x}$ *is* $e^{\frac 1 x \ln x}$ if x is irrational and positive. Also, $\log_{10}(x + 1)^2 = 2 \log_{10} |x + 1|$, so the domain is the same.

Comment: Take into account that for $x=-1$ for $x$ compared to $e^{\ln{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex.Jordan posted a nice answer but there is a domain that exists for ${x}^{1/x}$ if ${1/x}$ is reduced. Thus I don't believe his answer is proper to the OP's question.

When exponent of $x^{p/q}$ ,which is $p/q$, is reduced completely and $q$ is odd, $x^{p/q}$ satisfies the identities of $\sqrt[q]{x^p}$ and $\left(\sqrt[q]{x}\right)^{p}$ for the negative domain. Thus for ${x}^{1/x}$, we must find the values of $1/x$ where the output has an odd denominator and is completely reduced.

Also one should also know that for $f(x)^{g(x)}$ that $f(x)^{g(x)}\neq{e^{\ln(f(x))g(x)}}$ when $x<0$. This because $\ln(x)$ for the real logarithm is undefined at negative numbers. So they're is no reason to use this identity for figuring out the negative domain. Infact we must analyze $x^{1/x}$ strictly for the real domain.

One example is for $e^{\ln{x}}=x$ for $x<0$. When $x=-1$ the two terms are not the same.

Using all of my previous points, one can find the true domain of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is...

$(0,\infty)\bigcup{\left\{ {2n+1\over 2m+1}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}}\bigcup\left\{ {2n+1\over 2m}\ |\ n, m \in \Bbb Z\right\}$

For $f(x)^{g(x)}$, when one tries to search for the output of $g(x)$ that has a fraction reduced with an odd denominator; one can find the domain of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ when $f(x)$ is negative.

Be sure to check:

[Find the domain of $x^{2/3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109316/find-the-domain-of-x2-3)

[What is the domain of $x^x$ when $ x<0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398224/what-is-the-domain-of-xx-when-x0)

[Can the graph of $x^x$ have a real-valued plot below zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394110/can-the-graph-of-xx-have-a-real-valued-plot-below-zero)

[How can we describe the graph of $x^x$ for negative values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695701/how-can-we-describe-the-graph-of-xx-for-negative-values)