# $(-27)^{1/3}$ vs $\sqrt[3]{-27}$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Scrolling through questions I see that someone has claimed that the two are not the same. Why is  this so? And how would this effect evaluating the derivative of $\frac{3}{4}x\sqrt[3]{x}$ at $x=-27$ vs. the derivative of $\frac{3}{4}x^{4/3}$ at $x=-27$.

[What is the Domain of $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023630/what-is-the-domain-of-fx-x-frac1x)

Comment: Posted it @SubhadeepDey

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radix ,written as $\sqrt[3]{-27}$, refers specifically to the normal form of $(-27)^{1/3}$.  In the case of negatives, the normal form also includes a negative number.

The form $(-27)^{1/3}$ refers to any solution of the form $a^3=-27$, but when one is dealing with several values derived from $a^3=-27$, one should always use the same root.  In practice, using the radix-form is the normalized `first root` of the equation.

Comment: So the only solution to $\sqrt[3]{-27}$ is $-3$?

Comment: Yes.  They do this, because if one needs to access the other cube roots, you multiply it by a constant.  So while, eg [math]{4}^{1/2}=2, -2[/math], you write these as [math]\sqrt{4}, -sqrt{4}[/math].  Then you can rely on [math]\sqrt{4}[/math] being +2

Comment: Then why for text books is $x^{1/2}$ a function. This CAS standards versus general mathematical standards.  Perhaps you modify the CAS version of $x^{1/2}$ into $x=y^2$.